# How can I run a node app from the command line and return control?

Tags: node.js

I run a angular app like this:

npm run server-java

From a terminal window.
The server starts, but I want it to give back the shell prompt.

I want the shell prompt back while it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tools like [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) or [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to start your nodejs app as a background process. Usually used for production setup.

Another option is:

```
npm run server-java > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

You will get back to the terminal, but then you have to kill process manually by id when you don't need it.

Comment: I agree with Rashad. I would personally recommend forever - as it makes starting and stopping of node based instances easier to manage.